# Xcode NSUserDefaults settings lost when app is force quit

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults to save BOOLs that denote whether a mapped annotation is a "favorite".  The BOOLs are saved correctly when the User quits the app and then re-launches it.  However, when the User force quits (press the Home button twice and swipe up on the app) the app, the NSUserDefaults are lost.  Can someone please explain why this is happening?  I'm using Xcode v7.0.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

// If annotation is displayed, the User can save/clear annotation as a favorite
if ((_acmeMotorsIsDisplayed == YES) && (_acmeMotorsIsFavorite == YES)){
            _acmeMotorsIsFavorite = NO;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"acmeMotorsIsFavorite"];
        }
else if ((_acmeMotorsIsDisplayed == YES) && (_acmeMotorsIsFavorite == NO)){
            _acmeMotorsIsFavorite = YES;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"acmeMotorsIsFavorite"];
        }
}

-(void)loadUserDefaults{
// One of many lines of code that load user default settings
_acmeMotorsIsFavorite = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"acmeMotorsIsFavorite"];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self loadUserDefaults];
}
```

Comment: so many dupes of this question… is Google down??

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget about `synchronize` method.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"acmeMotorsIsFavorite"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried the synchronize command, but it didn't solve my problem, so I chose not to include it in my sample code.  The value of BOOL is correct in applicationWillResignActive.  However, the value of the BOOL in viewDidLoad when the app is re-launched is always NO.  I've tried dozens of solutions found on SO and other sites.  And this is particularly frustrating, as I have another app working perfectly.  Only difference is I'm using NSUserDefaults to save integers in the other app, not BOOLs.  Knowing this, any additional thoughts on why I'm not able to save BOOLs?

Answer (score 1):

When the user double taps Home the app delegate method `applicationWillResignActive:` is called, at that time synchronize `NSUserDefaults`:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```